# How to mock the boto3 client session requests for secretsmanager to either return a specific response or raise an exception

Tags: python, pytest, boto3, pytest-mock

Given code like:

```
def do_stuff():

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name=region_name)
    client.get_secret_value(SecretId=sendgrid_api_key_arn)
```

how do I mock
`client.get_secret_value("some-value")` to return some value

and how do I mock it to throw an exception

```
@patch("boto3.session")
def test_get_sendgrid_api_key_secret_when_client_error(mock_session):
        session = mock_session.Session();
        client = session.client()
        client.get_secret_value().return_value = 
                 {"SecretString": "my-secret"} <- this is wrapped in a MagicMock which is useless.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a tree of return values:

- `boto3.session.Session` needs to return a mock object
- That mock object needs a `client` method that returns another mock object
- And *that* mock object needs a `get_secret_value` method that returns a fake value

If I assume that `target.py` exists and contains:

```
import boto3.session


def do_stuff():
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name='myregion')
    return client.get_secret_value(SecretId='some-secret-id')
```

Then I can test it like this:

```
from unittest import mock

import target


@mock.patch("boto3.session.Session")
def test_do_stuff(mock_session_class):
    mock_session_object = mock.Mock()
    mock_client = mock.Mock()
    mock_client.get_secret_value.return_value = {'SecretString': 'my-secret'}
    mock_session_object.client.return_value = mock_client
    mock_session_class.return_value = mock_session_object

    res = target.do_stuff()
    assert res['SecretString'] == 'my-secret'
```

This works, although I suspect there's a more graceful way to set it
up.

Comment: what you mentioned is great, do you think it makes sense to convert that piece of code into a `@pytest.fixture`? if one needs those objects for multiple tests?

Comment: If you're doing something like this and need the same setup in multiple tests, then fixtures are a great way to make the code re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to patch `client.get_secret_value`, by adding one more decorator. Once this is done you an set the return_value to exception you need.

```
@patch("boto3.session")
@patch("boto3.session.Session.client.get_secret_value")
def test_get_sendgrid_api_key_secret_when_client_error(mock_session,second_fn):
        with pytest.raises('CustomException')
        session = mock_session.Session();
        second_fn.return_value = lambda : Exception('CustomException')
        client = session.client()
        client.get_secret_value()
```

When `client.get_secret_value()` is executed, test case will pass for raising the intended exception. Similarly instead of an lambda we can assign any other value to mock the return of function.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with patching `boto3.session` manually is that if you are using other AWS services aside from `secretsmanager`, then the mocked patch would be applied to everything, and this may not be what you want.

I propose here 2 solutions that are dedicated for patching/wrapping the secretsmanager functionality:

1. See **./test_secret_manual_amend.py** below. Intercept the `botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call.GetSecretValue` and control how the response would be. This is the more flexible solution as you can freely check the accessed secret-name, raise exceptions, and return anything you like.
2. See **./test_secret_using_moto.py** below. Use `moto.mock_secretsmanager`. This is the cleanest approach since this imitates how you would normally interact with the actual AWs secretsmanager. But probably a bit less flexible than solution-1.

### ./src.py

```
import boto3

sendgrid_api_key_arn = "some_name"
region_name = "ap-southeast-1"
credentials = {}


def do_stuff():
    session = boto3.session.Session(**credentials)
    client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name=region_name)
    return client.get_secret_value(SecretId=sendgrid_api_key_arn)
```

### ./test_secret_manual_amend.py

```
import botocore
import json
import pytest

from src import do_stuff, sendgrid_api_key_arn


def _amend_get_secret_value(secret_name, secret_value, mocker):
    orig = botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call

    def amend_make_api_call(self, operation_name, kwargs):
        # Intercept boto3 operations for <secretsmanager.get_secret_value>. Optionally, you can also
        # check on the argument <SecretId> and control how you want the response would be. This is
        # a very flexible solution as you have full control over the whole process of fetching a
        # secret.
        if operation_name == 'GetSecretValue' and kwargs["SecretId"] == secret_name:
            if isinstance(secret_value, Exception):
                raise secret_value
            return {
                'Name': secret_name,
                'SecretString': secret_value,
            }

        return orig(self, operation_name, kwargs)

    mocker.patch('botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call', new=amend_make_api_call)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'secret_value',
    [
        "some value",
        str(1993),
        json.dumps({"SecretString": "my-secret"}),
        json.dumps([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]),
        KeyError("How dare you touch my secret!"),
        ValueError("Oh my goodness you even have the guts to repeat it!!!"),
    ],
)
def test_secret_manual_amend(secret_value, mocker):
    _amend_get_secret_value(sendgrid_api_key_arn, secret_value, mocker)

    if isinstance(secret_value, Exception):
        with pytest.raises(type(secret_value)) as error:
            do_stuff()
        result = error
    else:
        result = do_stuff()

    print("Result:", result)
```

### ./test_secret_using_moto.py

```
import boto3
import json
from moto import mock_secretsmanager
import pytest

from src import do_stuff, sendgrid_api_key_arn


def _setup_secrets_manager(secret_name, secret_value):
    secret_manager = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    secret_manager.create_secret(
        Name=secret_name,
        SecretString=secret_value,
    )


@mock_secretsmanager
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'secret_value',
    [
        "some value",
        str(1993),
        json.dumps({"SecretString": "my-secret"}),
        json.dumps([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]),
    ],
)
def test_secret_using_moto(secret_value):
    _setup_secrets_manager(sendgrid_api_key_arn, secret_value)

    result = do_stuff()

    print("Result:", result)
```

### Output:

```
$ pytest -rP
====================================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================================
test_secret_manual_amend.py ......                                                                                                                                                        [ 60%]
test_secret_using_moto.py ....                                                                                                                                                            [100%]

============================================================================================ PASSES =============================================================================================


_____________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[some value] ______________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'Name': 'some_name', 'SecretString': 'some value'}
________________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[1993] _________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'Name': 'some_name', 'SecretString': '1993'}
____________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[{"SecretString": "my-secret"}] ____________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'Name': 'some_name', 'SecretString': '{"SecretString": "my-secret"}'}
____________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]] _____________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'Name': 'some_name', 'SecretString': '[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]'}
____________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[secret_value4] ____________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: <ExceptionInfo KeyError('How dare you touch my secret!') tblen=4>
____________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_manual_amend[secret_value5] ____________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: <ExceptionInfo ValueError('Oh my goodness you even have the guts to repeat it!!!') tblen=4>


______________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_using_moto[some value] _______________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'ARN': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:1234567890:secret:some_name-ghtZn', 'Name': 'some_name', 'VersionId': '42a45aad-8764-49fb-b1ad-67759063f804', 'SecretString': 'some value', 'VersionStages': ['AWSCURRENT'], 'CreatedDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 13, 15, 3, 43, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
_________________________________________________________________________________ test_secret_using_moto[1993] __________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'ARN': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:1234567890:secret:some_name-JdOXC', 'Name': 'some_name', 'VersionId': '098b2878-4368-4f25-b75d-942e82745257', 'SecretString': '1993', 'VersionStages': ['AWSCURRENT'], 'CreatedDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 13, 15, 3, 44, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
_____________________________________________________________________ test_secret_using_moto[{"SecretString": "my-secret"}] _____________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'ARN': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:1234567890:secret:some_name-jQgDK', 'Name': 'some_name', 'VersionId': '04bd6ceb-6ec9-427b-817c-c90360abfcd9', 'SecretString': '{"SecretString": "my-secret"}', 'VersionStages': ['AWSCURRENT'], 'CreatedDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 13, 15, 3, 44, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
_____________________________________________________________________ test_secret_using_moto[[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]] ______________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result: {'ARN': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:1234567890:secret:some_name-dQpLq', 'Name': 'some_name', 'VersionId': '94b7a169-c32b-4424-b47c-2dee2802c211', 'SecretString': '[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]', 'VersionStages': ['AWSCURRENT'], 'CreatedDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 13, 15, 3, 44, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
====================================================================================== 10 passed in 1.26s =======================================================================================
```